# History of new modes added to Google Maps' route planner?

Tags: google-maps

Does anyone know the timeline for the different modes added to Google Maps' route planner? I know they started with driving directions - what year was that? And when did they add options for biking, walking, and transit?

I'm asking because I'm doing a write-up on a little app I wrote that lets you compare the four modes side-by-side: see [Comparing Driving, Walking, Biking and Transit](http://www.mvjantzen.com/blog/?p=2684).

Answer (score 0):

- 2007: [Driving](http://googlemapsapi.blogspot.de/2007/05/driving-directions-support-added-to.html)
- 2008: [Walking](http://googlegeodevelopers.blogspot.de/2008/09/walking-directions-avoid-highways-my.html)
- 2010: [Bicycling](http://googlegeodevelopers.blogspot.de/2010/03/good-day-for-salesmen-that-travel-on.html)
- 2012: [Transit](http://googlegeodevelopers.blogspot.com.au/2012/06/public-transit-routing-and-layer-now.html)